# PingFederate SLO: NullPointerException org.sourceid.saml20.util.NameIdHashKey.equals

Tags: pingfederate

I am using PingFederate 7 as SP and mod_pf apache module integration kit. 
I have configured PingFederateSLOURL for making SLO logout call:

`PingFederateSLOURL https://<pingfederateurl>/?PartnerIdpId=<PartnerIdp URL>`

I am getting below error while making the /sp/startSLO.ping

`
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sourceid.saml20.util.NameIdHashKey.equals(NameIdHashKey.java:67)
        at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.sp.SloSupport.getByAdapterIdAndFirstCorrespondingPartnerIdPlus(SloSupport.java:131)
        at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.sp.SloSupport.chooseAuthnBeansAndSessions(SloSupport.java:77)
        at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.sp.CreateSloRequest.doProcess(CreateSloRequest.java:71)
        at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.RequestCreatorBase.process(RequestCreatorBase.java:50)
        at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.ProfileProcessManager.doCreateRequest(ProfileProcessManager.java:59)
        at $ProfileProcessMgmtService_15724fe023a.doCreateRequest($ProfileProcessMgmtService_15724fe023a.java)

`
I have configured SP adapter using OpentTokenAdapter.